# Query DBpedia for multiple keywords

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, sparql, semantic-markup, dbpedia

I want to query DBpedia for multiple keywords, when I query freebase for example using this:

```
http://api.freebase.com/api/service/search?query=%2BEgypt%2BPyramids
```

I get reasonable results like: "Egyptian Pyramids", "Ancient Egypt", "Pyramids of Giza (Egypt)".

However whenever I try to query dbpedia with multiple keywords I get an empty `ArrayofResult`, although when I query for each keyword on its own I do get results.. 
I couldn't find any documentation for DBpedia's Keyword search service, only this: http://dbpedia.org/lookup

I write the query like this:

```
http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=place&QueryString=Egypt+pyramid
```

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Work around to query DBpedia for two keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927643/work-around-to-query-dbpedia-for-two-keywords)

Comment: you can find answer to your question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927643/work-around-to-query-dbpedia-for-two-keywords

Answer (score 2):

Don't limit the results with place class, it seems doesn't work

http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryClass=&QueryString=Egyptian%20Pyramids