# Work around to query DBpedia for two keywords

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql, dbpedia

I want to query DBpedia for multiple keywords, apparently I have to search for an exact substring, so if I want the page about `Egyptian Pyramids`, searching for `Egypt Pyramids` won't work, but that's exactly what I need..

So I was thinking maybe I can see if the concept "Pyramids" has anything to do with "Egypt", by searching through the relations, but I am finding it difficult to come up with the sparql query needed for that

BTW I query through: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Answer (score 8):

Trying to construct a SPARQL query like the following might be useful:

```
SELECT ?uri ?txt WHERE {
                  ?uri rdfs:label ?txt .
                  ?txt bif:contains "'Egypt' OR 'Pyramid'" .
                 }
```

Or do you want something different?

Comment: By the way, bif: stands for built-in function, something unique to Virtuoso server which DBPedia uses, so do not take it as a fundamental part of SPARQL.