# create a DBPEDIA sparql

Tags: sparql, lookup, dbpedia

I am using lookup in dbpedia such as this http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=all%20by%20myself to extract all results containing the text "All by myself" but now I only want to extract those results in which the description contains the words "Eric Carmen" or better if  it can do a fuzzy selection such as pick both "Eric Carmen" and "Eric Karmen" in the description. Can anyone build a SPARQL for this? I have attached the result of the above url in this image. I have attached an answer from another query from stackoverflow [Work around to query DBpedia for two keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927643/work-around-to-query-dbpedia-for-two-keywords) to help you understand.
[image]

Comment: DBpedia Lookup is a simple fulltext index for RDF resources and does not support fuzzy matching. SPARQL is a query language for RDF and does not support fuzzy matching. Some triple stores support IR systems like Lucene, but DBpedia is hosted on Virtuoso and it does not support fuzzy matching. You could load DBpedia into your only triple store that does have extended fulltext search with fuzzy matching.

Comment: Suppose we don't use fuzzy matching then still how would the SPARQL code would be?

Comment: This depends on 1) the triple store that you use and 2) which RDF property you mean by "description".

Comment: you can accomplish a lot with the REGEX() function, maybe worth a try

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this query which returns all resources that contain your keyword in the abstract property:

```
SELECT Distinct *
Where
{          
     ?resource dbo:abstract ?abstract.      
     Filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN").        
     ?abstract bif:contains "Eric_Carmen".    
}
```

You can consider http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract as description of any resource in Dbpedia.